# First project with Zend framework on netbeans not working properly

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, indexing

I've installed the latest Zend Framework on the latest netbeans application and I've created my first project succesfully

The only problem I have is when I hit Run on netbeans it doesn't show the actual web page, it shows me the directory where I saved the project to instead of the Public folder.

I've followed the instructions on their quickstart guide but I can't seem to fix that problem.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Same probelem.
Running Ubuntu 10.10, netbeans 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure Netbeans to run your project correctly; it's not Zend's fault.

1. Right click on your project and select **Set as Main Project**, if not already
2. Right click again and select **Properties**
3. Under **Run Configuration**, choose **Run As:** and select **Local Web Site (running on local server**
4. Make sure your **Project URL** points to your web server (for example: http://localhost/myproject/)
5. Make sure your **Index File** is correct.

This all assumes that you are using a local webserver (example: Zend Server CE, or WAMP).

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment, but when I follow your steps I get an error when I choose my index file. I can choose in the public folder, so i choose the index.php in the public folder and when i run the url is http://localhost:8888/myproject/index.php so it doesn't seem to point to my public folder.

Comment: A few things to check: Make sure your hosts file is configured correctly, and make sure your virtual hosts file is configured correctly as well.

Comment: I think I did that as I should've done it, I'm on a mac and I've added a 127.0.0.1 myProject.local to the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and added virtual host configuration to the /etc/hosts

Comment: Netbeans will not modify your project in this way. The only thing you have to watch out for is that you don't publish your `nbproject` (at the root directory), which contains your Netbeans settings for that project.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem,
When you open `http://localhost/myproject/` it shows the directories, but when you try `http://localhost/myproject/public/` you can run the index.php file there, and see the default website.

Use the codes explained [Survive the Deep End](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts#zfbook.creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts.configuring.apache.with.virtual.hosts) and create a virtual host that uses public folder.

Simply, create a file named myproject.tld in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

then configured put the following codes to load from public folder, whenever you load it.

```
# Setup "myproject.tld" Virtual Host
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myproject.tld
DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/public

<Directory /var/www/myproject/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then used the commands

```
sudo a2ensite myproject.tld
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

And at last, edit /etc/hosts and insert the next line
    127.0.0.1       myproject.tld

After these, opening `http://myproject.tld/` will be working correctly.

Comment: Is this example for a mac or a ubuntu box?? I'm battling this problem at the moment... @reza

Comment: I used it on ubuntu 12.04 I think @DanielDC